# Dynamically adopt the methods of an instance of another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I have a case, where I have an instance of a class in python which holds instances of other classes. For my use case, I would like a way to use the methods of the "inner" classes from the outer class without referencing the attribute holding the inner class.

I have made a simplistic example here:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def say_hi(self):
        print("Hi")

    def say_goodbye(self):
        print("Goodbye")


class C:
    def __init__(self, other_instance):
        self.other_instance= other_instance

    def say_good_night(self):
        print("Good night")

my_a = A()
my_c = C(other_instance=my_a)

# How to make this possible:
my_c.say_hi()

# Instead of
my_c.other_instance.say_hi()
```

Class inheritance is not possible, as the object passed to C may be an instance of a range of classes. Is this possible in Python?

Comment: You could use `A.say_hi(my_c)` but I wouldn't advise it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the simplest solution although it is possible with metaprogramming.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def say_hi(self):
        print("Hi")

    def say_goodbye(self):
        print("Goodbye")


class C:
    def __init__(self, other_class):
        self.other_class = other_class
        C._add_methods(other_class)

    def say_good_night(self):
        print("Good night")

    @classmethod
    def _add_methods(cls, obj):
        type_ = type(obj)
        for k, v in type_.__dict__.items():
            if not k.startswith('__'):
                setattr(cls, k, v)


my_a = A()
my_c = C(other_class=my_a)

my_c.say_hi()
```

output :

```
Hi
```

First we get the type of passed instance, then we iterate through it's attribute (because methods are attributes of the class not the instance).

If `self.other_class` is only needed for this purpose, you can omit it as well.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Answer (score 0):

So, because you have done:
`my_a = A()` and `my_c = C(other_class=my_a)`.
`my_c.other_class` is the same as `my_a` asthey point to the same location in memory.

Therefore, as you can do `my_a.say_hi()` you could also do `my_c.other_class.say_hi()`.

Also, just a note, as you are calling `A()` before you store it into `other_classes`, I would probably rename the variable `other_classes` to `class_instances`.

Personally, I think that would make more sense, as each of those classes would have already been instantiated.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have altered my question, as what I am seeking is a way not to have to go through the attribute to call the methods.